# Extracting an image from param value and storing it in a variable

Tags: node.js, express

If we make a POST- request to the server

---

**Request**::

```
http://<---URL--->/upload/Key=string&Key1=Image
```

---

- **`Key`**=`param` having a text value called `string`
- **`Key1`**=`param` having a image value called `image`

---

**part of the code to handle post request** ::

```
var fs = require('fs');

    app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

        fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

            var imageName = req.files.image.name
```

**My Questions::**

1. What does the variable `imageName` contain ?
2. Does it contain `Image` which is a param value ? or else ?
3. How to store a Image which of one of the params to a variable ?

*I am new to express .... can someone explain how process takes place ?

Comment: What do you mean in 3? Where do you want to store the image (it's already been stored by node-formidable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the default [`node-formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) used by express, then `req.files` is an object containing all of the uploaded files' information (see [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files)):

- if the field in your upload form is named `image`, then `req.files.image.name` contains the filename of the uploaded file (ie. the name of the file on the user's hard drive);
- The query string parameters don't have anything to do with this. You can however access them using the [`req.params` object](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

Comment: Okie ... so if the name of the file is an image which is **image.jpg** ... then req.files.image.name contains image.jpg ... am i correct ?

Comment: If that's the name of the file on the user's computer when he tries to upload it, yes.